# Is there a simple way to conduct the this transformation on a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, pivot, transpose

See the attached image showing a DataFrame. I want to transform it in a way that is a combination of transposing and pivoting.

I can do it with NumPy arrays and two `for` loops, but is there a way to use other simple options?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

I used this data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'X', 1, 2], ['b', 'X', 3, 4], ['c', 'X', 5, 6]],
                  columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
                  )
```

Then you can achieve this with [`df.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), e.g. like so:

```py
(df.melt(id_vars=['C1', 'C2'],
         var_name='F1',
         value_name='F2')
   .sort_values('C1')
)
```

Result:

[image: The resulting dataframe]